# I get a error when ı use php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I get a error when I use to Php in Javascript. I check a console and Error name is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". How I solve this error

My code is;

```
var data = ["<?php
  foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM ev_uygunluk where evid='{$evid}' order by id ASC") as $listele) 
{
echo"
{date: ".$listele['tarih'].", value: 'rezerve'}";

}

  ?>"];
```

Console error line is;
[consol error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr2Yy.png)

Comment: I try add but again ı get a error. Where should I add in codes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having double quotes wrongly placed inside your brackets and your objects aren't separated correctly with commas. Try this instead:

```
<?php
$tmp = [];
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM ev_uygunluk where evid='{$evid}' order by id ASC") as $listele) {
    $tmp[] = "{date: '{$listele['tarih']}', value: 'rezerve'}";
}


echo "var data = [".implode(', ', $tmp)."]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma (s) is missing

```
var data = [ <?php
  foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM ev_uygunluk where evid='{$evid}' order by id ASC") as $listele) 
{
echo "{date: new Date('".$listele['tarih']."'), value: 'rezerve'}, ";  // this comma !
}
  ?> ];
```

Comment: sorry, ı get a  same error again.   error line is; https://imgur.com/8kNY1wE

Comment: @leatred  I changed my answer, removing double quotes, adding `new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

you should have use es6 back tick `` to avoid this type of mistake

var data = [`<?php
     foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM ev_uygunluk where evid='{$evid}' order by id ASC") 
     as $listele) 
     {
       echo"
       {date: ".$listele['tarih'].", value: 'rezerve'}";
       }
     ?>`];

I have used backtick but code editor not displaying it use `before <? and at after the end ?>` Hope this will solve your issue.